# Is it possible to store a base64 image as a string inside a json and send it as a payload to a post request?

Tags: json, mongodb, react-native, express

I wanted to save a user document in mongodb database including photos taken from a react-native application image picker. And I use express as my server

this is what I mean.

```
const res = await fetch('https://myServerUrl', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'myname',
        photos: [
            'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...' // very long string
            'data:image/png;base64,iVBORdqwweKGgoAAAasdSUhE...' // very long string
        ]
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json" // I'm not sure if I should use application/json
    }
    
})
```

I did this and my server crashes saying "request entity is too large"

What should I use as an alternative? or What I did wrong about this?

Comment: You can possibly upload the photo files - especially if they are large. You will have options to store within the document (upto 16 MB) or GridFS.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out that the problem is the limit of express json parsing.

I just change the limit like this...

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
```

The drawback is this is not performant.

Comment: base64 is heavy text, It's not reliable to save in database, Can you create endPoint which receives `BLOB` data and convert to specified image format (PNG, JPEG ) and generate file permanent URL. Otherwise you can use object cloud storage like AWS S3 or Firebase Storage